# Subquery returned more than 1 value how to solve?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
      outctc.year, 
      outctc.ctc, 
      outctc.gross, 
      (SELECT 
          (case when (COUNT(EMP_ID)>=1)then inrctc.ctc else outctc.ctc end)

      FROM 
          employee_ctc inrctc 
      WHERE 
          inrctc.EMP_ID = outctc.EMP_ID 
      GROUP BY 
          inrctc.ctc,inrctc.EMP_ID)  

FROM employee_ctc outctc  
WHERE outctc.EMP_ID=100002
```

**Error:**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server`

Comment: So you can use `limit 1` in your inner query

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, please elaborate

Comment: @MaheshMaske As the error clearly states, your subquery is returning more than one row. Based on your requirement use `top 1` or modify the query to return one row.

Comment: Why do you group by `inrctc.ctc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using a subquery inside a select, It is expected to return only 1 Single row and a column. So if you think there may be multiple rows or columns, and you need them all, then you should better use a CTE or use the Subquery in the join or where part.

Or even you can simply overcome the error by putting a Top 1 in the select.

here you are getting the error because in the Group BY part, you have given 2 column, but in the join part, there is only one. So in your table employee_ctc, there may be multiple records for the EMP_ID 100002

You can either add the remaining column (**inrctc.ctc**) to the join or remove that from the Group by

This might work for you :

```
select 
outctc.year,
outctc.ctc,
outctc.gross,
CASE WHEN Q.ctc IS NOT NULL
    THEN Q.ctc else outctc.ctc end
from employee_ctc outctc  
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        select 
            CTC = SUM(inrctc.ctc)
        from employee_ctc inrctc 
            where inrctc.EMP_ID=outctc.EMP_ID 
    )Q  
where outctc.EMP_ID=100002
```